# java does not support latin characters

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

I am running the following java program in eclipse. My string contain latin character.When I am printing the string it looks some weird. Here my code is

```
    String sample = "tést";
    System.out.println(sample);
```

Output:

```
    t?st
```

please help me. thanks in advance

Comment: Java supports latin char. in my environment i get the correct result.

Comment: Have you seen this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973987/how-to-use-latin-letters-in-eclipse

Comment: Which Java version ?

Comment: Look unter "Window"-->"preferences" end search for enc. Now you can see if you have set the correct encoding for your workspace.

Comment: Please show the example in hex, it will be easier to fix.

Comment: It is works on my local machine. When i am trying to run the same code on AWS, it is not accept latin characters

Answer (score 1):

The actual string *will* contain the latin character since Java strings are UTF-16. You could verify this with a good debugger.

It's the rendering on your console of the `println` call that is at fault.

Answer (score 0):

Java does support Latin characters.  Your display font at output probably doesn't. 
Other option is that you have strange (non-UTF) encoding in eclipse.

Comment: It is works on my local machine. When i am trying to run the same code on AWS, it is not accept latin characters

Answer (score 0):

I use netbeans, it works fine for me. See my output.

```
run:
tést
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use charset encoding as ISO-8859-1. This charset supports latin characters.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
out.println(sample);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this in Eclipse and reading the output from Eclipse's console, try this:

- Open `Run Configurations` (Menu `Run` > `Run Configurations`)
- Find the run configuration you're using
- Go to `Common` tab for that configuration
- In `Encoding` section choose UTF-8