# Convert Latin 1 supplementary unicode to string in java

Tags: java, string, type-conversion, iso-8859-1, unicode-string

I need to convert Latin 1 supplement unicodes to characters.

[image]

But in my program the same unicode is the output.

```
public static void convertUnicodeToCharacter(){
        String unicode ="\\U+00C3";
        System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(unicode));
}
```

But when I use the *String unicode ="\u0196";* it works fine. How can I solve this.

Comment: Does that help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32881336/9164071

Comment: @Themelis no I need to output the letter when inputting the unicode